# Business Object Pie Chart Conundrum

Tags: report, business-intelligence, business-objects

With the limitations of Business Objects (Launchpad 4.1 SP6), I need to construct a pie chart.  Simple enough but the dataset I'm required to use contains a code field that is evaluated, and depending on the string value returned, another field is summed (accrued minutes of a given activity described by the return code value).

For instance [Code] returns "BRK1" meaning break and evaluating to a number 15 (indicating 15 minutes).  Another [Code] returns "LUNCH" and evaluating to the number 60 (indicating a 60 minute lunch).  These types of codes return "Subtractive Codes", meaning they represent time subtracted from Scheduled Work.  Within the same [Code] field are also codes describing work segments.  For example: [Code] returns "SB_PHN_SOUTH" indicating a "shift bucket" that evaluates to 540 minutes.  The shift buckets are "Additive Codes".

So, given these business and programmatic rules, I have a dataset that looks like this:

```html
EWFMCodeSelect  EWFMPieChart
BREAK           2425685
DISC            443075
MISS            83476
NEUTR           2700
NODISC          582787
SHIFT           16120299
```

This can be easily turned into a pie chart but with one major error.  All of the groups, BREAK, DISC, MISS, NEUTR and NODISC are all Subractive and belong in the numerator.  The code SHIFT is the denominator.  SHIFT represents 9 hours of shift time, breaks and such subtract from the shift time so an accurate pie chart would show each subtractive bucket as a percentage of the whole "SHIFT" time.

I have two variables to group values into buckets for evaluation and summation:

```
=If([Code]InList("BRK1"; "BRK2"; "BRK3"; "LUNCH" )) Then"BREAK"
ElseIf([Code]InList("TEAM"; "MTG"; "PROJ"; "TRNG")) Then "DISC"
ElseIf([Code]InList("LATE";"NOSHOW";"UNPAID";"UPVAC")) Then "MISS"
ElseIf([Code]InList("COACH")) Then "NEUTR"
ElseIf([Code]InList("VAC";"LOA";"SICKUP";"SICKPL")) Then "NODISC"
Else("SHIFT")
```

and then:

```
=If([EWFMCodeSelect]="BREAK") Then Sum([TimeDiff (ToInt)]ForEach([Clndr Date];[Time-Interval];[Agent Login];[Code]))
ElseIf([EWFMCodeSelect]="DISC") Then Sum([TimeDiff (ToInt)]ForEach([Clndr Date];[Time-Interval];[Agent Login];[Code]))
ElseIf([EWFMCodeSelect]="MISS") Then Sum([TimeDiff (ToInt)]ForEach([Clndr Date];[Time-Interval];[Agent Login];[Code]))
ElseIf([EWFMCodeSelect]="NEUTR") Then Sum([TimeDiff (ToInt)]ForEach([Clndr Date];[Time-Interval];[Agent Login];[Code]))
ElseIf([EWFMCodeSelect]="NODISC") Then Sum([TimeDiff (ToInt)]ForEach([Clndr Date];[Time-Interval];[Agent Login];[Code]))
ElseIf([EWFMCodeSelect]="SHIFT") Then Sum([TimeDiff (ToInt)]ForEach([Clndr Date];[Time-Interval];[Agent Login];[Code]))
```

I've tried various techniques to Sum("SHIFT")-(InList("All other codes")) but I either get a #MULTIVALUE error (regardless of what Context Operators I've tried) or some other type of incorrect return value.

I've found no posts here or elsewhere describing a similar problem (or solution) so I'm hoping some fine Business Objects Webi expert here can suggest a path to solution.

Thank you for your consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest working towards a standard tabular table to get the values you want, then convert it to a Pie Chart from there.

Based on your description, I assume the values that you want to see in your chart are:

```
EWFMCodeSelect  
BREAK           15.0%
DISC             2.7%
MISS              .5%
NEUTR             .0%
NODISC           3.6%
```

This function should get you the percentages:

```
=[TimeDiff] 
/ NoFilter(( Sum([TimeDiff] 
                 ForAll([EWFMCodeSelect]) 
                 Where ([EWFMCodeSelect] = "SHIFT"))))
```

Since you don't want a pie for `[SHIFT]`, you will need to put a filter on the block to exclude it (The `NoFilter()` function in the formula brings `[SHIFT]` back in for evaluation)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Joe, I appreciate your help.  I removed the ELSE clause in the EWFMCodeSelect variable and filtered the report block to exclude the SHIFT values.  I used your formula in a new variable that I affectionately call EWFMPieChart(%), dropped the CodeSelect var in the block along with my new variable and I get #MULTIVALUE error across the board.  I've been tinkering with the usual ForEach combinations I've used to clear up Multivalue errors in other situations within this rpt but to no avail.  Any further suggestions?

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete formulas that you're using now?

Comment: Joe, after investigating further, I found the source of the error and it's within the data structure itself, not the code you generously supplied.  I'm working today to clean it up at the source, if successful I will retry the code and I expect this time it will work as you described.  I will keep you informed.

Comment: Thank you Joe, after cleaning up the source data this code worked as desired.