# filter by variable value in report block

Tags: report, business-intelligence, business-objects

I could find no relevant answers in either StackOverflow or google. Perhaps one of you has the answer.  This is [a continuation from a previous question..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466659/business-object-pie-chart-conundrum).

In Business Objects Webi, I have two variables.  One dimension, one measure.  My goal is to create a simple pie chart.

Here's the dimension variable titled "EWFMCodeSelect":

```
`=If([Code]InList("BRK1"; "BRK2"; "BRK3" )) Then"BREAK"
ElseIf([Code]InList("TEAM"; "MTG"; "MTNG"; "PROJ"; "TRNG";"WCGB")) Then "DISC"
ElseIf([Code]InList("LUNCH")) Then "LUNCH"
ElseIf([Code]InList("LATE";"NOSHOW";"UNPAID";"UPVAC")) Then "MISS"
ElseIf([Code]InList("COACH";"VTO")) Then "NEUTR"
ElseIf([Code]InList("VAC";"LOA";"SICKUP";"SICKPL")) Then "NODISC"
ElseIf([Code]InList("PREP")) Then "OTHER"
ElseIf([Code]InList("OVER")) Then "OVER"
Else("SHIFT")`
```

This is the measure variable titled EWFMPieChart(%):

```
=[TimeDiff (ToInt)]
/ NoFilter(( Sum([TimeDiff (ToInt)]
ForAll([EWFMCodeSelect])
Where ([EWFMCodeSelect] = "SHIFT")))ForEach())
```

The previous advice I received was to filter the value "SHIFT" from the report block.  I thought this would be a simple affair but it's proving more difficult than anticipated.  I tried creating a Report Block filter in the Analysis tab "EWFMCodeSelect Not Equal To SHIFT"
"EWFMCodeSelect Not In List > SHIFT"

but only ended up with a single row, the dimension field empty, the measure field showing #MULTIVALUE.  I tried a variety of other combinations but all had the same effect.

I tried a Column filter:

```
=[EWFMCodeSelect] Where ([EWFMCodeSelect] <> "SHIFT")
```

but ended up with a single row, the dimension field showing: "BREAKDISCLUNCH..." as the value and the measure, again, showing #MULTIVALUE.

I'm missing some important clue here.  Can anyone educate me either why this approach is incorrect and maybe supply me with a direction to achieve my goal?

Thanks,
mfc

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the correct answer but I did solve the problem by cleaning up all of the TEST variables, deleting all unused and unnecessary errata that collected up to this point and re-running the report as a scheduled item.  I also cleared the browser cache (never bad advice).

After re-opening the report, I was able to filter the report block without issue.

I guess the answer is "When in doubt and receiving undocumented results, clean up your work-space and try again".